# It the planning entity must have one to one relationship with planning value?

Tags: java, hibernate, optaplanner

I need to plan an employee to task roster system but I need multiple tasks to be assigned to multiple employees , so that the relationship between them is many to many. However I can not find any effective example in optaplanner's official document, all their examples are many to one relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace a many-to-many relationship A-B with a one-to-many A-C and many-to-on C-B. Several of the examples do that, for example the `ShiftAssignment` class is the C between the `Shift` and the `Employee` class.